# Unsure why this Dafny verification fails

Tags: dafny

```
function method abs(m: int): nat
{ if m>0 then m else -m }

method CalcTerm(m: int, n: nat) returns (res: int)
  ensures res == 5*m-3*n;
{
  var m1: nat := abs(m);
  var n1: nat := n;
  res := 0;

  while (m1!=0)
    invariant m1>=0
    invariant 0<=res
    invariant res <=5*abs(m)
    decreases m1
  {
    res := res+5;
    m1 := m1-1;
  }
  if (m<0) { res := -res; }

  while (n1!=0)
    invariant n1>=0 
    decreases n1
  {
    res := res-3;
    n1 := n1-1;
  }
}
```

I have tried to increase the invariance in the loops. To the first loop, I added the condition, res<=5*abs(m) but Dafny complains that "This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop." I don't understand how it is not.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your loop invariant stronger by stating exactly what `res` is equal to after each iteration, Dafny will be able to verify it.

So in the first while loop, instead of `invariant res <= 5*abs(m)`, use `invariant res == 5*abs(m) - 5*m1`. When the loop terminates, `m1` is equal to zero, so `res` will be `5*abs(m)`.

Similarly, for the second while loop, define the `invariant res == 5*m - 3*n + 3*n1`. Now when this loop terminates, `n1` is equal to zero, so `res` will be `5*m - 3*n` and Dafny will be able to prove that the post-condition of the method holds.

P.S. I usually use `> 0` instead of `!= 0` as a loop condition.

After making these changes, you would have:

```
function method abs(m: int): nat
{
    if m > 0 then m else -m
}

method CalcTerm(m: int, n: nat) returns (res: int)
    ensures res == 5*m - 3*n;
{
    var m1: nat := abs(m);
    var n1: nat := n;
    res := 0;

    while (m1 > 0)
        invariant m1 >= 0;
        invariant 0 <= res;
        invariant res == 5*abs(m) - 5*m1;
        decreases m1;
    {
        res := res + 5;
        m1 := m1 - 1;
    }
    if (m < 0)
    {
        res := -res;
    }

    while (n1 > 0)
        invariant n1 >= 0;
        invariant res == 5*m - 3*n + 3*n1;
        decreases n1;
    {
        res := res - 3;
        n1 := n1 - 1;
    }
}
```

which verifies in Dafny.